# How to repair SigSegV

Tags: c++

I was doing a problem where you need to find the best K figures to eliminate from N so the number would have the minimum difference between the smallest and highest figure.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int diff(vector <int> x){
    sort(x.begin(),x.end());
    return x.back()-x[0];
}

int diffMin(vector<int> x,int h,int best){
   if(h==0) return diff(x);
   else{
       for(int a=0;a<x.size();a++){
           int y=x[a];
           x.erase(x.begin()+a);
           best=min(best,diffMin(x,h-1,best));
           x.insert(x.begin()+a,y);
       }
   return best;
   }
}

int main(){
    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    vector <int> x;
    while(n!=0){
        x.push_back(n%10);
        n/=10;
    }
    cout<<diffMin(x,k,10);
}
```

I put it in an evaluator but it said "Caught fatal signal 11(SigSegV )". Could someone explain me why?

Comment: did you use a debugger to step through your code? `x.erase(x.begin()+a);` inside a loop with condition `a<x.size()` looks suspicious.

Comment: Yes,I did.It doesn't give me any error. The x.erase(x.begin()+a); inside the loop is to eliminate a digit, verify the value ,then it is added back. @idclev463035818

Comment: the debugger does not give you errors, rather it helps you so that **you** can spot the errors

Comment: please include example input in your question

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)